# Using Wordpress solely as a Backend - dealing with WP_SITEURL

Tags: angular, wordpress, dns, hostname, jetpack

I've built a website in Angular that leverages Wordpress as a backend, specifically using its REST API. I am replacing an existing website, and my client does not intent to change their hostname. Initially I was hoping to publish Angular's static files to a CDN at their original hostname (myclient.com) and move their Wordpress to api.myclient.com. In this scenario my client would log in at api.myclient.com/login to manage their content there as well.

This is where I am starting to have some concern. I noticed a few issues, which are problematic, and I'm hoping someone might have a smart solution. The issues are as follows:

1. When I go to api.myclient.com/login and login, I am redirected to myclient.com/wp-admin, which is my CDN, so I cannot login.

Initially I found [this solution](https://gist.github.com/davejamesmiller/1965636), which outlines a way to allow my client to log into wp-admin at any domain. However, this presented a few other problems.

1. Jetpack is giving me warnings about entering safe mode because the Wordpress site has changed domains
2. If I create a new post, my RSS feed has links pointing to api.myclient.com rather than myclient.com
3. Publishing my website to social media links to api.myclient.com/post-slug rather than myclient.com/post-slug

Has anyone else run into this issue? My problems seem mainly related to jetpack, so if this is not the right forum for this kind of question please let me know!